# AnkhSVN not Recognizing my Solution as being in Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn

I did not go the route of using the ankhSVN context menu in VS to add my solution to SVN.  I went the route (because I prefer to and like how tortoise does this) of using Tortoise to add my folder/project to SVN for the first time.

Then when I opened that solution, VS opens but ankhSVN still did not flag my files or recognize a connection to svn.

what's the deal?  I don't want to be forced to only use ankhSVN to commit a project for the first time to SVN in order for ankhSVN to bind or recognize and kick in.

Answer (score 23):

Most likely, AnkhSVN isn't loaded yet at this point. Go to Tools - Options - Source Control, and select AnkhSVN as the active SCC Provider. Then go to File - Subversion - Change Source Control, and connect/bind the solution. This causes Ankh to be loaded the next time you open the solution by annotating the sln file. Other people checking out the same sln file also benefit from this, because Ankh is then loaded directly.

Comment: Yay, my solution wasn't connected. Great place to check that all projects are connected, over just re-adding them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The times I had this issue it was because SVN was updated and ankhSVN didn't support the type.  I fixed this by either rolling back the SVN update or install the lastest version of ankhSVN which sometimes is the beta version.

Comment: Yes, this is important too, make sure your SVN Version # matches the SVN Version # that came with the Ankh install.

Comment: Or more acurately, make sure your TORTOISE and ANKH both use the same SVN version #

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, usually this fixes it:

Right click on the solution node of the Solution Explorer. In the context menu, go to Subversion... Refresh Status.

Or as Stefan points out, just use the Ankh toolbar in Visual Studio.

Comment: AnkhSvn does not notice when you do something with TortoiseSvn. In such cases you need to use the Refresh as Neil indicated. It is maybe a bit more convenient / faster to use the Toolbar that AnkhSvn provides...

Comment: I didnt even realize there was a toolbar, I've always just used the context manus in the solution explorer.  Thanks!

Comment: 14 years later, all change we get now that even that button doesn't work now. And ankhSVN seemingly at random ignores files, even if they were edited in IDE. Sometimes Rescan or re-opening solution fixes it